# Creating image grid on products page in wordpress

Tags: theme-development

how can i create such product page image layout in astra theme, tried many gallery plugins but unable to get this kind of look. Please if anyone can help
[image]

Comment: Should just be able to do it with CSS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.